# $p,q,r$ th term of an AP and GP are $a,b,c$ respectively

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $p,q,r$ th term of an AP and GP are  $a,b,c$ respectively I need to find the value of $a^bb^cc^a-a^cb^ac^b$

taking first term and common difference as $m,d$ I wrote three usual equation  from the given information. and taking first term and common ration as $k,t$ I wrote three equation..but not able to understand how to proceed next...
thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notation $m$ as first term $d$ is common difference for AP and $k$ as first term , $t$ as common ration for GP. We get the following
\begin{align*}
a&=kt^{p-1} &&& a&=m+(p-1)d\\
b&=kt^{q-1} &&& b&=m+(q-1)d\\
c&=kt^{r-1} &&& c&=m+(r-1)d
\end{align*}
From these you can get
\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{b}&=t^{p-q} &&& a-b&=(p-q)d\\
\frac{b}{c}&=t^{q-r} &&& b-c&=(q-r)d\\
\frac{c}{a}&=t^{r-p} &&& c-a&=(r-p)d
\end{align*}
Furthermore these set of equations give
$$
\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{a-b}}=\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^{\frac{1}{b-c}}=\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{c-a}}.
$$
Now simplify and you will get your answer as $0$.